# Запуск VirtualBox в нестандартном режиме

Tags: virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Можно ли запустить VirtualBox так, чтоб не выводилось никакое окно?
То есть даже окно которое выводит рабочий стол виртуальной машины?
Слышал что это можно сделать при помощи `cmd`, то есть запустить ВМ в безголовом режиме, можно больше конкретики?

Comment: Так уж несколько лет у кнопочки запуска ВМ есть пункт «Запустить в фоновом режиме»

Comment: Если вас даже окно с кнопочкой запуска ВМ не устраивает, то вроде бы по запросам вида «virtualbox headless» команды cmd неплохо ищутся